# How to match data not in groups (sql or SAS)

Tags: sql, sas

There are two columns in the main table X1. A and B. A is date and B is people names. I want to find people not on each date by has historial record before.
For example, Tom and Liliy have records on 5/2, I want to find people before 5/2 except them.
I try to join the table with itself on previous data, but don't know how to avoid same names in historial record.

```
Table X1             
A   |   B               
5/1     Tom             
5/1     Liliy           
5/1     Jack            
5/2     Tom
5/2     Liliy
```

Here is my expected result:
    Table   X2
    A    |   B
    5/2     Jack

Comment: Does "not in X2" mean a match just on column `B`, or column `A` as well?

Comment: (Feel free to edit your question, but not at the cost of throwing my good edits away please. See the edit history before editing).

Comment: Sorry, I have finished editing now. A is included. I want to find unmatch part before each date. Thank you.

Comment: And what result would you want?  The explanation is not particularly clear.

Comment: Thank you, halfer. I am still new on stack overflow. Thank you for all the kind suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all people except those two and assuming that `A` is actually a date column then you can do the following SQL query.

```
SELECT *
FROM X1
WHERE A < Convert(datetime, '5/2') AND B NOT IN ('Tom', 'Liliy');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. You will get back the date and names of those who only appear once in the column. If there are multiple instances of the same name, then the `COUNT(B)` will be greater than one.

```
SELECT A, B
FROM X1
GROUP BY B
HAVING COUNT(B) = 1
```

Comment: This is just sample data, actually there are many dates and records

Comment: @Sylvia Given your example, this would solve your issue despite how many dates and records there are. Can you show us your output and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I can only think of an answer similar to `@Jonathan Porter`'s

Below is to have a larger starting dataset to work with:

```
/*Generate a more diverse starting dataset*/
data X1;
    format A mmddyy9.;
    array names [10] $ 20 ('Phillip','Wendi','Virgilio','Scotty','Melony','Rayford','Vince','Cody','Julissa','Marquerite');
    do i=1 to 30;
        A = intnx('DAY', '01MAY2017'd, ceil(ranuni(3)*10));
        B = names[ceil(ranuni(3)*10)];
        output;
    end;
    drop names: i;
run;
proc sort data=X1 nodups;
    by A B;
run;
```

Starting dataset X1:

```
A           B
----------------------
5/2/2017    Rayford
5/2/2017    Virgilio
5/3/2017    Cody
5/3/2017    Melony
5/3/2017    Rayford
5/3/2017    Wendi
5/4/2017    Scotty
5/5/2017    Rayford
5/5/2017    Wendi
5/6/2017    Rayford
5/6/2017    Vince
5/7/2017    Marquerite
5/7/2017    Virgilio
5/8/2017    Julissa
5/8/2017    Rayford
5/9/2017    Cody
5/9/2017    Julissa
5/9/2017    Marquerite
5/9/2017    Virgilio
5/9/2017    Wendi
5/10/2017   Julissa
5/10/2017   Phillip
5/11/2017   Cody
5/11/2017   Vince
```

Group by name, retrieve count and latest associated date:

```
proc sql;
    create table X2 as
    select max(A) as latest_A format=mmddyy9., /*Latest date to which a name (B) is associated*/
           B,                                  
           count(*) as count_B                 /*Count of records associated with a given name (B)*/
    from X1
    group by B;
quit;
proc sort data=X2;
    by latest_A B;
run;
```

As Jonathan stated, I assume you're interested in the records with asterisks in X2 below:

```
latest_A    B           count_B
------------------------------------
5/3/2017    Melony      1       ***
5/4/2017    Scotty      1       ***
5/8/2017    Rayford     5
5/9/2017    Marquerite  2
5/9/2017    Virgilio    3
5/9/2017    Wendi       3
5/10/2017   Julissa     3
5/10/2017   Phillip     1       ***
5/11/2017   Cody        3
5/11/2017   Vince       2
```